# Is it possible to use Http4k to upload to an Amazon S3 bucket with a presigned-url?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3, http4k

I'm currently using an AWS recommended method of uploading to an S3 bucket using a presigned url that is detailed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

```
// Create the connection and use it to upload the new object using the pre-signed URL.

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write("This text uploaded as an object via presigned URL.");
out.close();

// Check the HTTP response code. To complete the upload and make the object available, 
// you must interact with the connection object in some way.

connection.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("HTTP response code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
```

I would like to instead do this using Http4k. Is such functionality possible with this toolkit? If so, could somebody please direct me in the right direction?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? The docs claim that "http4k provides a simple and uniform way to serve, consume, and test HTTP services." Did you try this? Do you have any code?

Comment: My problem is that there is very sparse documentation for this library and it's not at all popular either, so it's difficult to find examples of how to work with it. I know how to pass in objects can be accessed as body parameters, but I don't know how to set the inputStream directly using this package

Comment: Limited documentation and unpopular doesn't sound encouraging. The AWS Java SDK includes a TransferManager that can accept streamed uploads via [PutObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html) afaik.